# Unable To Get Stored Object Value Via Key In Firefox

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Let's say I had an array `test` that was stored via `GM_setValue('test', []);` when the script has been run for the first time to ensure that it's there.

Now if I were to assign the local variable `test` to this via `var test = GM_getValue('test');`, push a new object at some point in the script like so `test.push({id: '...'});` and then save over it by doing this `GM_setValue('test', test);` the stored array would be this `[{ id: '...' }]`.

Now I need to get the value with the key `id` from the object in the array later in the script, so I'll simply do this `test[0]['id']`. However this appears to return *undefined*.

Alrighty, it's possible it's not storing the object for some reason, so here's what I'll do:

```
console.log(test);
console.log(test[0]);
console.log(test[0]['id']);
```

Amazingly, `test` returns an Array containing the object and in turn the id, `test[0]` returns the Object containing the id with the correct value, however `test[0]['id']` still returns *undefined*.

This works perfectly on Chrome with Tampermonkey, but the problem arises when the script is running on Firefox with Greasemonkey. What could the problem possibly be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GM_setValue` does not store objects; it stores strings or integers. See [the doc page](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue).

Use a serializer like [GM_SuperValue](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/107941).

Comment: Oh yep, I am not a smart man. I even flicked through that page a couple of times too. I'm surprised I'm not dead from drinking expired milk yet. Thank you!